# Python - Setting up server with Websocket

Tags: python, apache, nginx, websocket

I'm new with these things, but I already know some basics of Python. I would like to create some advanced script with some framework and websocket, but I actually don't know a lot about that. I've read that's necessary to have two servers (nginx, apache) to particularly serve system files (for example django) and media files. This script will for now allow to chat with other people, but after I get some experience with some framework, I will extend usability.

So I have few questions for you:

- Which framework should I choose to run Websocket and it's light?
- Is possible to run websocket in background and not only from console?
- Do I really need two servers to run some framework on Python?
- How to set up apache to run [insert framework] powered website?
- What's the difference between PHP MVC frameworks and [insert framework] structure?

Comment: Your questions cover a lot of ground and build on each other.  I would suggest restating to list your requirements for a framework and waiting to ask your last two questions fr specific frameworks after the refined question has been answered.